# how can I accelerate this MySQL query (count distinct & join)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, distinct

Do you have any idea, how I can accelerate a following query?

```
select count(distinct t1.var1)
from table_a t1
join table_b t2 on t1.var2 = t2.var1
   and t2.date between '2016-11-05 00:00:00' and '2016-11-10 23:59:59'
   and t2.var3 = 3;
```

I've tried this way:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct t1.var1 from table_a t1
join table_b t2 on t1.var2 = t2.var1
   and t2.date between ('2016-11-05 00:00:00') and ('2016-11-10 23:59:59')
   and t2.var3 = 3 ) as temp
```

but it's not faster than previous one

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query . In addition, questions about query performance always require an EXPLAIN

Comment: That said, a covering index on the 3 t2 columns seems like a good idea

Comment: Upon review, i believe that this question is offtopic and voted to have it closed.  One should not ask for coding help (how to do something) but rather present a problem that might be useful to other users.  Read these guidelines on how to pose a question in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2):

```
select count(distinct(t1.var1))
from table_a t1
join (select * from table_b where date between ('2016-11-05 00:00:00') and ('2016-11-10 23:59:59') and var3 = 3) t2 
on t1.var2 = t2.var1;
```

Apply the fiters before performing the join

Comment: select only the required data from the table instead of selecting all the data and then joining it

Comment: which approach @marmas

Comment: your @prashant :)

Comment: thanks @marmas..happy to help....@Strawberry please upvote my answer as that is the one which is correct

Comment: No, it is not really correct. Without explain and knowing what existing indexes there are, you are just guessing.

Comment: This is not a guess....it is a tried and tested approach.....which is a known alogrithm for optimizing queries....

Comment: Note that I have not added any extra column in the filter.....so I am using whatever indexes are present.....if you feel this is wrong please provide a counter scenario where this solution will not work...

Comment: I don't believe that there's any 'trying' or 'testing' taking place here. Please reference the algorithm.